# How to get a tessel microcontroller to connect to firebase

Tags: firebase, tessel

I am trying to connect my tessel to firebase, and I have tried everything. Is anyone else having a similar problem? I have read that the tessel uses different web sockets than firebase, but I am really new and don't know much about that. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit to include some of the things you have tried? This helps a lot in giving advice.

Comment: @katie-hurley: I see you've made a number of edit suggestions today. We prefer that edits be substantial, so you should be making any other improvements you can on those questions, rather than sending them for review with such minor changes. If you want to discuss, feel free to drop into the [SOCVR chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), where I or any other user present would be happy to help.

Comment: @Mogsdad My apologies.  I was looking at time-series specific questions and noticed that quite a few relevant questions to time-series did not have the tag specified.  I thought it would be helpful to ensure they are categorized correctly and did not intentionally mean to create more work for moderators.  Sorry again for the mistake but I will take this into consideration in the future.

Comment: @KatieHurley - Thanks for responding! No big worries - the tag edits you are doing appear appropriate, but some reviewers (self included) will tend to reject any that do nothing else to improve posts. I'd just like to encourage you to be thorough. See the tips [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). And like I said, if you want to drop into chat anytime, there's a slew of experienced curators willing to help you. Cheers!

Comment: @Mogsdad Thanks so much for the feedback and guidance. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Glad to hear that people are interested in using Firebase with the Tessel. I'm one of the Firebase engineers who has been working with the Tessel folks to make this happen. There are two Tessel Forum posts that give some more detail on the problem:

1. [Firebase cannot be compiled by Colony](https://forums.tessel.io/t/firebase-cannot-be-compiled-by-colony/231/2)
2. [Websockets on Tessel](https://forums.tessel.io/t/using-websockets/821)

The Firebase node packages uses faye-websockets, which the Tessel compiler couldn't support. We got nodejs-websockets to compile, and built a version of the Firebase library to test the concept. I was able to read and write from Firebase using the Tessel, but we were very hesitant to release a separate version of Firebase to NPM just for use on the Tessel, especially since nodejs-websockets is not as well maintained as faye-websockets. I then spent an evening working with the Tessel folks to get faye-websockets working, and it now compiles, with the changes sitting out on a branch (tessel/runtime/JH-HTTPParser). I don't have a timeframe on these getting merged into Master and being shipped out to production, but I know there are a good number of SSL and websocket based API's who are waiting on these changes to hit the main branch.

TL;DR: Firebase compiles on the Tessel (you can build the code off the above branch), and it can either read or write (not both at the same time). When I get some more time, I will be debugging Tessel + Firebase to get this working correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't tl;dr be first, in case it's too long and I didn't read? =o)

Comment: Hi Mike/Kato - are there any updates on getting firebase working with the tessel?

Comment: I'm excited to use this!

Comment: Tessel just came out with the Tessel 2, which works with Firebase right out of the box: see [our blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-03-06-firebase-plus-tessel-equals-awesome.html) and [their announcement](https://tessel.io/blog/112787427217/tessel-2-new-hardware-for-the-tessel-ecosystem). I might still tinker with Colony to see if we can overcome the issues that currently exist, but I think the T2 is the way forward on this.

Answer (score 1):

With the acquisition I haven't had much time to try. Last time I checked, things were compiling and running for some operations (I haven't tested everything) if we used a non-minified version of the Firebase library (not currently provided to end users). The issue here is that the minification puts all the variables in the same line, and the Tessel Lua VM would complain that there were more than 200 variables and wouldn't like it. I can play around with it some over the next week and see where things are, otherwise I can ping Jon and the Tessel folks to see how we can best move this issue along.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [SynergyKit](https://synergykit.com) for realtime communication. You can download Node.js library, which is fully supported by tessel platform and using websocket library, which is one of few libraries written in pure javascript.

You will be able to live observing all data in collections and sending messages. There is [documentation](https://cloud.synergykit.com/documentation/nodejs) for Node.js.